# Помогите пожалуйста со вставкой

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Всем привет, нужна помощь со вставкой. Программа должна вставить столбец в конец массива, после последнего столбца, аналогичным образом вставить строку. При этом они должны состоять из максимальных элементов той строки или столбца, после которого они стоят. Проблема такова: почему-то отказывается работать функция `add_row` хотя `add column` прекрасно работает. А так же не понимаю как сделать что бы вставленные строка или столбец состояли из максимального элемента, и как его найти. Заранее спасибо!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
 
 
int** get_empty_array(int n, int m)
{
    int **arrDouble;
    arrDouble = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arrDouble[i] = new int [m];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
        {
            arrDouble[i][k] = 0;
        }
}
return arrDouble;
}

int** get_array(int n, int m)
{
    int **arrDouble;
    arrDouble = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arrDouble[i] = new int [m];
    }
    srand(time(0)); 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
        {
            arrDouble[i][k] = rand() % 10;
        }
}
return arrDouble;
}
 
void ShowDoubleArray(int** arr,int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        cout << setw(4) << arr[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
        cout << endl;
}
void add_column(int** &arrDouble, int& rows, int cols, int count = 0)
{
    int *temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        temp = arrDouble[i];
        arrDouble[i] = (int *) malloc((cols+1)*sizeof(int));
        for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++)
        {
            arrDouble[i][k] = temp[k];
        }
        arrDouble[i][cols] = count;
    }
    cols++;
}
void add_row(int** &arrDouble, int cols, int& rows, int count = 0)
{
    int** temp;
    rows++;
    temp = arrDouble;
    arrDouble = get_empty_array(rows, cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows-1; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++)
        {
            arrDouble[i][k] = temp[i][k];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
            arrDouble[rows-1][i] = count;
     }
}

int main()
{
    int **arrDouble;
    int rows, cols;
    cout << "Input rows: "; cin >> rows;
    cout << "Input cols: "; cin >> cols;
    arrDouble = get_array(rows, cols);
    ShowDoubleArray(arrDouble, rows, cols);
    
    add_column(arrDouble, rows, cols);
    cols++;
    add_row(arrDouble, rows, cols);
    rows++;
    
    ShowDoubleArray(arrDouble, rows, cols);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        delete[] arrDouble[i];
    }
    delete[] arrDouble;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Похоже, что в функции `add_row` вы допускаете суперскую утечку памяти. Вы не уничтожаете `temp` после извлечения чисел из него. Более того, в вашей программе как она есть -- вы не увеличи количество строк перед вызовом `add_row` и он просто создал таблицу с одной колонкой больше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данное решение прилагается как доработка к коду, представленным автором. К сожалению, полностью сделать код адекватным не удалось да и тем более автор в силу незнания пытается использовать `C-style`. Пусть так и будет

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int** getZeroFilledMatrix(int n, int m)
{
    int **arrDouble;
    arrDouble = new int*[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arrDouble[i] = new int[m];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
        {
            arrDouble[i][k] = 0;
        }
    }

    return arrDouble;
}

int** getRandomFilledMatrix(int n, int m)
{
    int **arrDouble;
    arrDouble = new int*[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arrDouble[i] = new int[m];
    }

    srand(time(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
        {
            arrDouble[i][k] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }

    return arrDouble;
}

void printDoubleArray(int** arr, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            cout << setw(4) << arr[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int getMaxElementOfArray(int* arr, int size) {
    if (arr == nullptr || size < 1) {
        exit(1);
    }

    int maxElem = arr[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > maxElem) {
            maxElem = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return maxElem;
}

int** add_column(int** arrDouble, int rows, int& cols, int count = 0) {
    auto extendedByColumnMatrix = getZeroFilledMatrix(rows, cols + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            extendedByColumnMatrix[i][j] = arrDouble[i][j];
        }
    }

    printDoubleArray(extendedByColumnMatrix, rows, cols + 1);

    cols++;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        extendedByColumnMatrix[i][cols-1] = getMaxElementOfArray(arrDouble[i], cols-1);
    }

    printDoubleArray(extendedByColumnMatrix, rows, cols);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        delete arrDouble[i];
    }

    delete arrDouble;
    arrDouble = nullptr;
    
    return extendedByColumnMatrix;
}

int** add_row(int** arrDouble, int& rows, int cols, int count = 0) {
    auto extendedByRowMatrix = getZeroFilledMatrix(rows + 1, cols);

    printDoubleArray(arrDouble, rows, cols);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            extendedByRowMatrix[i][j] = arrDouble[i][j];
        }
    }

    printDoubleArray(extendedByRowMatrix, rows + 1, cols);

    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        auto elementOfColumn = new int[cols];

        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            elementOfColumn[i] = arrDouble[j][i];
        }

        extendedByRowMatrix[rows][i] = getMaxElementOfArray(elementOfColumn, cols);

        delete elementOfColumn;
        elementOfColumn = nullptr;
    }

    rows++;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++) {
        delete arrDouble[i];
    }

    delete arrDouble;
    arrDouble = nullptr;

    return extendedByRowMatrix;
}

int main()
{
    int **arrDouble;
    int rows, cols;
    cout << "Input rows: "; cin >> rows;
    cout << "Input cols: "; cin >> cols;
    arrDouble = getRandomFilledMatrix(rows, cols);
    printDoubleArray(arrDouble, rows, cols);

    arrDouble = add_column(arrDouble, rows, cols);
    arrDouble = add_row(arrDouble, rows, cols);
    
    printDoubleArray(arrDouble, rows, cols);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        delete[] arrDouble[i];
    }
    delete[] arrDouble;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Кстати, на компиляторе `VS 2019` код падал, когда я пытался изменить указатель, передаваемый в качестве параметра, а так же я столкнулся с некоторыми особенностями, возникшими в ходе оптимизации компилятора. Этот код абсолютно небезопасный

Comment: Спасибо, а можно еще вопрос. Вот все в порядке, но строка которая вставляется просто дублируется как последняя из исходного массива, а как сделать что бы она тоже состояла из максимальных элементов

Comment: @Zhenyadze так оно сейчас и делается в `add_row`. Если я верно понял условие, то надо каждый столбец новодобавляемой строки заполнить максимальным значением из столбца. Сейчас это и делается. Сперва столбец записывается в `elementOfColumn`. Оттуда берется максимальное значение, а затем ставляется в строку

Comment: Да вы все правильно поняли, но почему то строка которая вставляется всегда совпадает с последней строкой исходного массива

Answer (score 1):

Этот код делает то, что вы хотите. Здесь матрица - это шаблонный класс, параметры шаблона это размер матрицы

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

template<int RowSize, int ColumnSize>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix() {
        std::cout << "Please, enter elements for matrix!" << std::endl;
        fillMatrix();
    }

    template<int RowSize2, int ColumnSize2>
    bool operator==(Matrix<RowSize2, ColumnSize2> matrix) {
        if constexpr (RowSize != RowSize2) {
            std::cout << "Row sizes of matrices are different";
            return false;
        } else if (ColumnSize != ColumnSize2) {
            std::cout << "Column sizes of matrices are different";
            return false;
        } else {

        }
    }

    int getMaxElement() const {
        std::vector<int> max_elements_over_all_rows(RowSize);

        std::transform(matrix_.begin(), matrix_.end(), max_elements_over_all_rows.begin(), [](const auto& row) {
            return *std::max_element(row.begin(), row.end());
        });

        return *std::max_element(max_elements_over_all_rows.begin(), max_elements_over_all_rows.end());
    }

    int getMinElement() const {
        std::vector<int> max_elements_over_all_rows(RowSize);

        std::transform(matrix_.begin(), matrix_.end(), max_elements_over_all_rows.begin(), [](const auto& row) {
            return *std::min_element(row.begin(), row.end());
        });

        return *std::min_element(max_elements_over_all_rows.begin(), max_elements_over_all_rows.end());
    }

    void addRow() {
        const auto &last_row = matrix_.back();
        addRowWithValue(*std::max_element(last_row.begin(), last_row.end()));
    }

    void addColumn() {
        std::vector<int> last_column(RowSize);

        std::transform(matrix_.begin(), matrix_.end(), last_column.begin(), [](const auto& row) {
            return row.back();
        });

        addColumnWithValue(*std::max_element(last_column.begin(), last_column.end()));
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix_ = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(RowSize, std::vector<int>(ColumnSize));

    void addRowWithValue(int value)  {
        std::vector<int> addingRow(ColumnSize);
        std::fill(addingRow.begin(), addingRow.end(), value);

        matrix_.push_back(addingRow);
    }

    void addColumnWithValue(int value) {
        std::for_each(matrix_.begin(), matrix_.end(), [value = value](auto& row) { row.push_back(value); } );
    }

    void fillMatrix() {
        for(int i = 0; i < RowSize; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < ColumnSize; j++) {
                int value;
                std::cin >> value;

                matrix_.at(i).at(j) = value;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Matrix<3, 3> matrix;

    matrix.addColumn();
    matrix.addRow();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но нельзя ли попроще? Тут слишком сложно для меня.

Comment: К сожалению, не знаю как тут перейти в приватное обсуждение, но комментариев по вашему коду я могу дать очень много...

Comment: Все же основная проблема в вашем в коде то, что вы в функции `add_row` не используете 
 `get_empty_array` как реаллокатор (см. realloc). Вы просто берете указатель на динамически созданный массив данных. Потом "отрываете" текущий указатель и к нему присваиваете адрес НОВОГО динамически созданного объекта (гляньте внимательно в  `add_row`  вы создаете функцию точно с таким же размером), а потом переписываете со старого массива в новый, как бы получая одно и тоже и при этом вы НЕ вычищаете старый. Если звучит не очень доступно, могу объяснить подробнее

Comment: Честно говоря звучит понятно, но я не смогу это реализовать. Не могли бы вы мне пожалуйста помочь? и как найти макс элемент строки или столбца и присвоить его новой строке или столбцу который вставляется...

Comment: Если только к завтра, сегодня увы не получится

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду ждать